# Retries are not happening after the first retry on a broken circuit

Tags: c#, asp.net, polly

I have the following policies:

```
var sharedBulkhead = Policy.BulkheadAsync(
            maxParallelization: maxParallelizations, 
            maxQueuingActions: maxQueuingActions,
            onBulkheadRejectedAsync: (context) =>
            {
                Log.Info($"Bulk head rejected => Policy Wrap: {context.PolicyWrapKey}, Policy: {context.PolicyKey}, Endpoint: {context.OperationKey}");
                return TaskHelper.EmptyTask;
            }
        );

var retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<Exception>(e => (e is HttpRequestException)).WaitAndRetryAsync(
            retryCount: maxRetryCount,
            sleepDurationProvider: attempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, attempt)),
            onRetryAsync: (exception, calculatedWaitDuration, retryCount, context) =>
            {
                Log.Error($"Retry => Count: {retryCount}, Wait duration: {calculatedWaitDuration}, Policy Wrap: {context.PolicyWrapKey}, Policy: {context.PolicyKey}, Endpoint: {context.OperationKey}, Exception: {exception}.");
                return TaskHelper.EmptyTask;
            });

            var circuitBreaker = Policy.Handle<Exception>(e => (e is HttpRequestException)).CircuitBreakerAsync(
            exceptionsAllowedBeforeBreaking: maxExceptionsBeforeBreaking, 
            durationOfBreak: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(circuitBreakDurationSeconds), 
            onBreak: (exception, timespan, context) =>
            {
                Log.Error($"Circuit broken => Policy Wrap: {context.PolicyWrapKey}, Policy: {context.PolicyKey}, Endpoint: {context.OperationKey}, Exception: {exception}");
            },
            onReset: (context) =>
            {
                Log.Info($"Circuit reset => Policy Wrap: {context.PolicyWrapKey}, Policy: {context.PolicyKey}, Endpoint: {context.OperationKey}");
            }
        );

var fallbackForCircuitBreaker = Policy<bool>
         .Handle<BrokenCircuitException>()
         .FallbackAsync(
             fallbackValue: false,
             onFallbackAsync: (b, context) =>
             {
                 Log.Error($"Operation attempted on broken circuit => Policy Wrap: {context.PolicyWrapKey}, Policy: {context.PolicyKey}, Endpoint: {context.OperationKey}");
                 return TaskHelper.EmptyTask;
             }
         );

var fallbackForAnyException = Policy<bool>
            .Handle<Exception>()
            .FallbackAsync(
                fallbackAction: (ct, context) => { return Task.FromResult(false); },
                onFallbackAsync: (e, context) =>
                {
                    Log.Error($"An unexpected error occured => Policy Wrap: {context.PolicyWrapKey}, Policy: {context.PolicyKey}, Endpoint: {context.OperationKey}");
                    return TaskHelper.EmptyTask;
                }
            );


var resilienceStrategy = Policy.WrapAsync(retryPolicy, circuitBreaker, sharedBulkhead);
        var policyWrap = fallbackForAnyException.WrapAsync(fallbackForCircuitBreaker.WrapAsync(resilienceStrategy));
```

I execute the policy like so:

```
Task.Run(() =>
        {
            foreach (var changeMessage in changeMessages)
            {
                policyWrap.ExecuteAsync((context) => CallApi(changeMessage), new Context(endPoint));
            }
        });
```

No retries happen after the first call to `fallbackForCircuitBreaker`. I want the retries to happen as per the wait duration regardless of the state the circuit is in.

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: The posted code is executing the async tasks without awaiting them: `await Task Run(...)` and `await policyWrap.ExecuteAsync(...)` would be more usual - unless you intentionally want to fire-and-forget the async tasks. If fire-and-forget is intended, it may be worth considering what the code should do for exceptions which would otherwise become [unobserved task exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5/).

Comment: Yes. That is intentional. Won't the unhandled exceptions be caught by `fallbackForAnyException`?

Comment: The unhandled exceptions will not be caught be `fallbackForAnyException`, because the outcomes of the `Task`s representing the async work are not being observed in any way, in the posted code. I would suggest reading [any general articles on exception handling in async code](https://www.google.com/search?q=exception+handling+in+async+c%23), and the [previously linked article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5/) for a deep discussion of unobserved task exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No retries happen after the first call to fallbackForCircuitBreaker. I want the retries to happen as per the wait duration regardless of the state the circuit is in.

The retry policy is not configured to handle `BrokenCircuitException`, only `HttpRequestException`.

To make the retry policy retry also for `BrokenCircuitException`, configure the policy:

```
var retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
    .Or<BrokenCircuitException>()
    .WaitAndRetryAsync( /* etc */ );
```

---

*Note*: If only the above change is made, the sequencing of policies in the `PolicyWrap` posted in the question:

```
.., fallbackForCircuitBreaker, retryPolicy, circuitBreaker, sharedBulkhead
```

will mean `fallbackForCircuitBreaker` will only be invoked if all retries fail, and if the last retry fails with `BrokenCircuitException`.  See [PolicyWrap documentation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap).

Comment: What changes should be made in order for `fallbackForCircuitBreaker` to be invoked every time a retry is made on a broken circuit?

Comment: One more question, I have declared `sharedBulkhead` as an instance property in a service. It is initialized in the constructor. Is that a good practice?

Comment: Please raise these questions as separate Stack Overflow questions; Stack Overflow prefers us to avoid answering questions in comments, and answers may be too long for comments.

Comment: Will do that. Meanwhile, can you take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942022/how-to-wrap-transienthttperror-retry-policy-with-circuit-breaker-and-bulkhead-po

Comment: Have added the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944139/fallback-for-circuit-breaker-not-invoked-on-all-retries-on-the-broken-circuit