# How to use policy wrap on RetryPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, polly

I have the following retry policy which uses `Polly.Extensions.Http`:

```
var retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<BrokenCircuitException>().OrTransientHttpError().WaitAndRetryAsync
                (
                    retryCount: maxRetryCount,
                    sleepDurationProvider: attempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, attempt)),
                    onRetryAsync: (exception, calculatedWaitDuration, retryCount, context) =>
                    {
                      //Code
                    }
                );
```

I want to wrap the policy with circuit breaker and bulk head policies:

```
var circuitBreaker = Policy.Handle<HttpRequestException>().CircuitBreakerAsync(
            exceptionsAllowedBeforeBreaking: maxExceptionsBeforeBreaking,
            durationOfBreak: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(circuitBreakDurationSeconds),
            onBreak: (exception, timespan, context) =>
            {
              //Code
            },
            onReset: (context) =>
            {
                //Code
            }
        );

var sharedBulkhead = Policy.BulkheadAsync(
            maxParallelization: maxParallelizations,
            maxQueuingActions: maxQueuingActions,
            onBulkheadRejectedAsync: (context) =>
            {
                //Code
            }
        );
```

I use the following code to wrap the policies together:

```
Policy.WrapAsync(retryPolicy, circuitBreaker, sharedBulkhead);
```

This is giving an error:

> can not convert from 'Polly.Retry.RetryPolicy<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>' to 'Polly.IAsyncPolicy'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When policy configuration uses [`.HandleTransientHttpError()` or `.OrTransientHttpError()`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#extending-the-convenience-addtransienthttperrorpolicy-definition), the policies are configured to handle [specific status code results](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#extending-the-convenience-addtransienthttperrorpolicy-definition) of an execution returning `HttpResponseMessage`.

This makes the returned policies of a type which fulfils the generic interface `IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>` rather than the non-generic `IAsyncPolicy`.

To create a generic `PolicyWrap<TResult>` using the [PolicyWrap static syntax](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap#static-syntax) you must specify the generic type parameter explicitly:

```
Policy.WrapAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(retryPolicy, circuitBreaker, sharedBulkhead)
```

If you use the [PolicyWrap instance syntax](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap#instance-syntax), the compiler can usually infer the syntax. So the following should also be sufficient:

```
retryPolicy.WrapAsync(circuitBreaker).WrapAsync(sharedBulkhead)
```

---

Polly documentation covers the differences between non-generic and generic policies, in general, in [the readme](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#handing-return-values-and-policytresult) and [wiki](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Non-generic-and-generic-policies).